# Matcher.group and Regular Expressions Not extracting full regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a `String`

```
String s = "adfgadfbfgadg sa 2419sfgh";
```

I am trying to extract the substring

```
String substring = "sa 2419sfgh";
```

with Pattern and Matcher using the following regular expression and code.

```
formNumberRegex = "[al|sf|sa|sc|nrc|nrc form|doe|doe f|lsi|doe form psd f|doe al f]?[\\s\\-\\.]*[\\d]{3,6}[\\s\\-\\.]*[\\w]{1,4}";
formNumberRegexPattern = Pattern.compile(formNumberRegex);
formNumberMatcher = formNumberRegexPattern.matcher(s);

if (formNumberMatcher.find()) {
    String substring = formNumberMatcher.group();
}
```

However, I am only getting

```
substring = "a 2419sfgh";
```

What is wrong with my regular expression and/or Matcher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Immediately, I notice:

```
[al|sf|sa|sc|nrc|nrc form|doe|doe f|lsi|doe form psd f|doe al f]?
```

should be:

```
(?:al|sf|sa|sc|nrc|nrc form|doe|doe f|lsi|doe form psd f|doe al f)?
```

The "non-capturing group", (?: ), lets you avoid capturing that first part as an initial group.  This way, the whole expression is "match group 0" and that's it.

Tested here: http://regex101.com/r/lS9dT2

Answer (score 1):

You are using [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[...]`

```
[al|sf|sa|sc|nrc|nrc form|doe|doe f|lsi|doe form psd f|doe al f]
```

instead of [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

```
(al|sf|sa|sc|nrc|nrc form|doe|doe f|lsi|doe form psd f|doe al f)
```

What you used can be written as

```
(\\||a|l|s|f|s|a|s|c|n|r|c|n|r|c| |f|o|r|m|d|o|e|d|o|e| |f|l|s|i|d|o|e| |f|o|r|m| |p|s|d| |f|||d|o|e| |a|l| |f)
```

so since character class will match only one character from all used inside `[...]` it will accept `|` or `a` or `l` or `s`... and so on, while corrected version will accept only one of cases separated by OR like `al` or `sf` and so on.

So change your regex to

```
String formNumberRegex = "(al|sf|sa|sc|nrc|nrc form|doe|doe f|lsi|doe form psd f|doe al f)?[\\s\\-\\.]*[\\d]{3,6}[\\s\\-\\.]*[\\w]{1,4}";
```